# Laravel Model IDE Helper and Enum Types

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I'm using the [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) to generate autocompletion for my models. I've also started using [Laravel Enum](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) for certain columns. Is there an automated way to combine the Artisan `ide-helper:models` `enum:annotate-model` functionality so that my models are correctly annotated?

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

Enum:

```
namespace App\Enums;

use BenSampo\Enum\Enum;

final class Category extends Enum
{
    const ONE = 0;
    const TWO = 1;
    const THREE = 2;
}
```

Migration:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Enums\Category;

class CreateEnumTests extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('enum_tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('category')->default(Category::ONE);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('enum_tests');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace App;

use BenSampo\Enum\Traits\CastsEnums;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Enums\Category;

class EnumTest extends Model
{
    use CastsEnums;

    protected $enumCasts = [
        'category' => Category::class,
    ];
}
```

Result of `php artisan ide-helper:models -rW "\App\EnumTest"`:

```
/**
 * \App\EnumTest
 *
 * @property int $category
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest newModelQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest newQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest query()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest whereCategory($value)
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */
```

After running `php artisan enum:annotate-model "\App\EnumTest"`:

```
/**
 * \App\EnumTest
 *
 * @property \App\Enums\Category|null $category
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest
 * newModelQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest
 * newQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\EnumTest
 * query()
 * @method
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */
```

The previous phpDocBlock gets mangled, and `$category` isn't nullable.